# C++ - Pass member function to member object with std::function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to pass a member function object to a member object but I am getting the following error in VS 2013:

```
error C2664: 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,>::_Set(std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from '_Myimpl *' to 'std::_Func_base<_Ret,> *'
```

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Bar {
public:
    Bar(){};
    Bar(std::function<void(void)> funct_) : funct(funct_){}

    void setFunct(std::function<void(void)> funct_){
        funct = funct_;
    }
    void run(){
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
            funct();
    };
    std::function<void(void)> funct;

};

class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){
        bar.setFunct(&Foo::printSimpleFoo);
    }

    void printSimpleFoo(){
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }

    void start(){
        bar.run();
    }

private:
    Bar bar;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.start();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

So I want `Bar` to be able to take an arbitrary function with the specific signature, i.e. `void(void)` from its parent object and the call it in its `run()` member function (which will be called by the parent's `start()` member function)

I have looked into similar questions. Many suggest using std::mem_fn but when it is not clear to me how to use it in this setting (where the function has to be passed to different object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired function signature is `void (*)(void)` however the signature of `printSimpleFoo` is `void (Foo::*)(void)`.

You can use `std::bind` to capture the object instance. The object instance is necessary because you cannot call a member function with the associated object instance. The `std::bind` essentially stores the object instance so that the function has the appropriate signature.

`bar.setFunct(std::bind(&Foo::printSimpleFoo, this));`

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar() {}

    Bar(std::function<void(void)> funct_) : funct(funct_) {}

    void setFunct(std::function<void(void)> funct_)
    {
        funct = funct_;
    }

    void run()
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
        {
            funct();
        }
    };

    std::function<void(void)> funct;
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        bar.setFunct(std::bind(&Foo::printSimpleFoo, this));
    }

    void printSimpleFoo()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    }

    void start()
    {
        bar.run();
    }

private:
    Bar bar;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.start();

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Code Output

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/xSJvMa)